# On AIX, grep -B -A -m does not work. Any solution with sed or awk

Tags: shell

I am on AIX system. But `grep` on AIX does not support `-B`, `-A`, `-M` on AIX system. Are there other solutions like `awk` or `sed` which can do the same job?

For example:

```
str1
str2
str3
str4
str9
str8
str1
str3
str2
```

I try to run `grep str3 -m 1 -B 1 -A 1` to get:

```
str2
str3
str4
```

but it does not work on AIX. Is there any solution for `sed` or `awk`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 awk 'c&&c--;/str3/{print p;print $0;c=1}{p=$0}' file
```

Comment: thx! Could you please explain the command a little bit. which parameter is set up for line number before the matching like -B in grep. which one is set up for line number after the matching like -A in grep

Comment: use c to set up after the line. (you can use any number for c). use `p` for before the line. However, for this I only give you answer for the equivalent of `-A 1`. Have to do it another way if you want to specify the number.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a circular buffer which you print when the match is found, followed by the matched line, followed by the additional lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    B = 4              # set these values like you would use for grep -B, -A, -m
    A = 2
    m = 3

    patt = "999"       # set this to your regex

    i = 0
    B++                # the buffer will hold B lines plus one for the match
}

{
    a[i] = $0          # accumulate B (+1) lines in a circular buffer
    i = (i + 1) % B
}

$0 ~ patt {            # if the pattern is found print the contents of the buffer
    for (j=1; j<=B; j++) {
        print a[i]
        i = (i + 1) % B
    }
    split("", a)
    for (i=1; i<=A; i++) {    # print the next A lines
        getline
        print
    }
    if (--m == 0) exit        # output m matches then quit
    print "---"
}
```

A more sophisticated script would accept options and arguments rather than having to edit it to change them.

As a compromise, you could rearrange things a little and pass arguments using AWK's `-v` option.

Answer (score 2):

By the way, congratulations and +1 for providing sample input and output.  You would be surprised how many questions are missing such obvious specifications...

This can be done with ed(1).

```
so ross$ cat >> cg.ed
/str3/-1;.+2p
so ross$ ed - cg.txt < cg.ed
str2
str3
str4
so ross$
```

You can make a script out of this that will take the filename and pattern as arguments:

```
so ross$ cat > cg.sh
#!/bin/sh
ed - $1 << eof
/$2/-1;.+2p
eof
so ross$ sh cg.sh cg.txt str3
str2
str3
str4
so ross$
```

Comment: thank you for ur reply. i never use ed command before. i will try that. How about awk or sed?

Answer (score 2):

I have a 78-line shell script that does the job.  I later replaced it with a 114-line Perl script, but normally port GNU `grep` where I need the facility.  The shell script follows - it uses a different nomenclature for the options (AFAIK, it predates the options on GNU grep; it was certainly developed independently of the options in GNU grep).

```
#!/bin/ksh
#
# @(#)$Id: old.sgrep.sh,v 1.5 2007/09/15 22:15:43 jleffler Exp $
#
#   Special grep
#   Finds a pattern and prints lines either side of the pattern
#   Line numbers are always produced by ed (substitute for grep),
#   which allows us to eliminate duplicate lines cleanly.  If the
#   user did not ask for numbers, these are then stripped out.
#
#   BUG: if the pattern occurs in in the first line or two and
#   the number of lines to go back is larger than the line number,
#   it fails dismally.

set -- `getopt "f:b:hn" "$@"`

case $# in
0)  echo "Usage: $0 [-hn] [-f x] [-b y] pattern [files]" >&2
    exit 1;;
esac

# Tab required - at least with sed (perl would be different)
# But then the whole problem would be different if implemented in Perl.
number="'s/^\\([0-9][0-9]*\\)   /\\1:/'"
filename="'s%^%%'"      # No-op for sed

f=3
b=3
nflag=no
hflag=no
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
    -f) f=$2; shift 2;;
    -b) b=$2; shift 2;;
    -n) nflag=yes; shift;;
    -h) hflag=yes; shift;;
    --) shift; break;;
    *)  echo "Unknown option $1" >&2
        exit 1;;
    esac
done
pattern="${1:?'No pattern'}"
shift

case $# in
0)  tmp=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/`basename $0`.$$
    trap "rm -f $tmp ; exit 1" 0
    cat - >$tmp
    set -- $tmp
    sort="sort -t: -u +0n -1"
    ;;
*)  filename="'s%^%'\$file:%"
    sort="sort -t: -u +1n -2"
    ;;
esac

case $nflag in
yes)    num_remove='s/[0-9][0-9]*://';;
no)     num_remove='s/^//';;
esac
case $hflag in
yes)    fileremove='s%^$file:%%';;
no)     fileremove='s/^//';;
esac

for file in $*
do
    echo "g/$pattern/.-${b},.+${f}n" |
    ed - $file |
    eval sed -e "$number" -e "$filename" |
    $sort |
    eval sed -e "$fileremove" -e "$num_remove"
done

rm -f $tmp
trap 0
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

this little coding will highlight the regexp and works like grep -A -B -m
Hope this helps.

Christian Knauer

```
#!/bin/bash
[ $# -lt 2 ] && printf "usage: %s <regex> <file> [[[back]forward]occurrence] \n" "$0" && exit 0
REGEX=$1
FILE=$2
BACK=${3:-1}
FORWARD=${4:-1}
STOP=${5:-1000000000}
awk -v bold=$'\e[1m' -v norm=$'\e[0m' -v back=$BACK -v forward=$FORWARD -v stop=$STOP 'BEGIN {cnt=0} { array[i++]=$0 }
     END {
       maxI=++i
       for (j=0;j<maxI; j++) {
         if (array[j] ~ /'"${REGEX}"'/) {
           for (z=back;z>0; z--) {
             print array[j-z]
           }
           printf bold > "/dev/stderr"
           printf("%s\n", array[j])
           printf norm > "/dev/stderr"
           for (x=1;x<=forward; x++) {
             print array[j+x]
           }
           cnt++
           if (cnt == stop) {
             break
           }
         }
       }
     }
   ' "$FILE"
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly simplified [DigitallRoss' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5062981/7551394) that additionally prints ALL matching lines, not only first one matching the `str3` pattern:

```
echo ',g/str3/-1;+2p' | ed - myFile.txt
```

where

```
,                 # read all lines (from first to the very last)
 g/str3/          # search for `str3` string
        -1        # take 1 line BEFORE the matching one
          ;+2     # and also next 2 lines (so 3 lines in total)
             p    # and print them
```

If you want to print only FIRST occurrence then the command is simpler:

```
echo '/str3/-1;+2p' | ed - myFile.txt
```

where

```
/str3/          # find line matching the `str3` string
      -1        # take 1 line BEFORE the matching one
        ;+2     # and also next 2 lines (so 3 lines in total)
           p    # and print them
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need 3 lines after the str9, Here is an easy one

Input file

```
$cat <<'EOF' > strfile.txt
str1
str2
str3
str4
str9
str8
str1
str3
str2
EOF
```

Search for str9 and print the line + 3 lines ( including the file name. Handy while searching for a large number of file *.txt

```
$awk '/str9/{print FILENAME;n=NR+3} n>=NR' strfile.txt

strfile.txt
str9
str8
str1
str3
```

Comment: good approach for -A 1 (print the line after the found one). do you have some more ideas for the other requirements? (-m 1 = find only the first occurrence, -B 1 = print the line before the occurrence)?