# Errror string catch: redundancy with grep command

Tags: unix, aix

Currently I am using the following command to catch the Error String in the MY_FILE_NAME*.log

```
Currentdate=`date -u +"%Y/%m/%d"`
YEST=`TZ=XYZ+24 date '+%Y/%m/%d'`

grep -E "$Currentdate|$YEST"  MY_FILE_NAME*.log |  grep "Type: Error"
```

This command is generating huge data with the string "Type: Error" with redundancy in the same error type (in my case the same error is displayed like 100 times)

I want the error strings of same type to be displayed only once

Answer (score 1):

If using GNU/Linux try the '-m' switch

```
grep -m 1 -E "$Currentdate|$YEST"  MY_FILE_NAME*.log |  grep "Type: Error"
```

In the GNU version of grep, the '-m ' switch stops reading the input file after  matches are found. This feature does not exist in the older Unix grep on which AIX and similar are built.

If on AIX where there is no -m or -B see [this StackOvreflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062882/on-aix-grep-b-a-m-does-not-work-any-solution-with-sed-or-awk)

Comment: It says "grep: Not a recognized flag: m"

Comment: What OS and distro are you using? Hint: type 'uname -a'.

Comment: I use AIX and I login through putty

Comment: See referenced stackoverflow post

Comment: Edited answer to address comment

Comment: In my case I have different type of errors with common string "Type:Error" in the log file and each error repeats n times. I want the output with each type of error present only once.

Comment: Please edit the question to include example lines from the log file.